# Is the practice of calling others by initials acceptable?

Tags: word-usage

The answers and comments on my question about English alternatives to “Senpai” reminded me of the odd feeling I used to have almost 25 years ago when I observed my client’s staffs were referring to each other or others by initial (e.g., T.H, K.A) in conversation in the meeting.

I wasn’t sure of whether it is common American practice to call or refer to others, even their seniors by initials. I wondered then if it’s special corporate culture of the client (which happened to be a renowned American financial service company), or just in jest.

Though this was an internal matter, and may be special case I witnessed, I’ve seen several cases of a person(s) being mentioned by the initials in public.
 For instance, Maureen Dowd always refers to the former President by **G.W**., or **W**. in public.

Time magazine features disagreement of Saudi Arabia and U.S. under the headline, "**The King and O** (King Abdullah and Barack Obama)" in its April 7 2014 issue.

Tina Fey calls her old boy friend like “I met HRW (note: representing for a handsome Robert Wuhl) the next morning at his off-campus apartment,”“HRW motioned for me to sit down near him,” “It was surprise by the time HRW dropped me off,” (P.56-59), and even abbreviatesstrong YMCA as “**The Y** had a preschool attached to it,” (P.66) in her million-seller book, “Tina Fay Bossypants.

Is it accepted, or very uncommon practice to refer to other person by the initial in English speaking countries? Isn't it rude to call others by the initials like "Hey, K.A. What's your opinion," and "I don't agree J.K's idea."?

Comment: It isn't all that common, Y. O..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about culture and not the English language.

Comment: It's not done randomly – there's usually a reason for it. Perhaps the person identifies themselves by their initials (i.e., it's an established nickname). Other times, it might help disambiguate (if an office has two people named John, workers might start calling one of them J.B., for example). I wouldn't call it customary. It could be taken as rude, but, among friends, you can sometimes get away with it, and it might even be well-received. It partly depends on the demeanor of the folks involved.

Comment: It can easily be interpreted as a sign of disrespect. For example, the use of **Dubbya** for George W. Bush was meant to highlight perceived "yokelism". J.R.'s comment is a good answer.

Comment: It's not common practice but would be seen as a nickname, so it would be as normal/acceptable as any other nickname - it could be friendly, satirical or derogatory. Here's a different [J.R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_shot_J.R.%3F)

Comment: _The King and O_ is surely a parody of the title of the musical _The King and I_.

Comment: @CanisLupus A language is all about the culture though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question depends upon the culture about which you are speaking.

In America for example, it's not done unless as a nickname.  And, generally, this would only be between peers who are friendly. Or, someone whose name is something like Dan, Jr., might go by D.J. (Dan Junior).

When I was in medical school, however, I had a number of Indian professors and associates who used their first initials in place of their first names.  For example: Dr. T.S. Ranganathan was always referred to as T.S. by his colleagues in casual conversation.

Comment: I have seen the same with Indian colleagues, although usually the starting letters of first and last name were used. With only one exception, I haven't _heard_ them addressing each other like that though - the initials were used in writing _about_ others.

Comment: @oerkelens That might have been a local cultural phenomenon. And, I had also seen the same phenomenon with initial and last name, too. But, it was definitely a form of address at meetings. I think because of the sheer number of Drs. Patel it became necessary to address them as Dr. M. Patel, Dr. RJ Patel, etc.

Comment: I occasionally see that sort of thing in emails and forums to refer to people as a sort of pronoun, but I would be surprised to hear it said out loud.

Comment: @BraddSzonye It struck me as strange enough to stick in my memory for over 15 years!